# Retrieving images to 3 image views (Firebase and Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimage, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

From this node in JSON structure:

```
{
  "Devices" : {
    "WDREMca1BOcaaW457Mg8ankzId32" : {
      "Device1" : {
        "Category" : "",
        "Description" : "",
        "DeviceName" : "",
        "ImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jabeerah-c27c3.appspot.com/o/Devices_Images%2F5F4E0AC2-8279-4CC4-AE99-E797655D4331.png?alt=media&token=5823ed16-e8ff-4b85-8a64-bfb00b965785"
      },
      "Device2" : {
        "Category" : "",
        "Description" : "",
        "DeviceName" : "",
        "ImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jabeerah-c27c3.appspot.com/o/Devices_Images%2FF9E2EF8D-44B3-4BE6-9020-81D190A45AA3.png?alt=media&token=af17e9a5-53f4-4054-9496-fb86d1508a6f"
      }
     },
       "a4gbFozO4gTZE6QT60b6qxQDriw2" : {
  "Device1" : {
    "Category" : "أخرى",
    "Description" : "mmm",
    "DeviceName" : "mmm",
    "ImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jabeerah-c27c3.appspot.com/o/Devices_Images%2FCF13F154-2B5F-4926-A979-2E187BD0E504.png?alt=media&token=bf1b876f-9f9a-4e78-9e8d-98d017fd0404"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the users' pictures to his/her profile. 
The profile view has 3 image views (Since each user can have only 3 devices or less).

In viewDidLoad function I have made this:

```
   if ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Device1") != nil  {

ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Device1").observe(.value , with: {snapshot in
    let ImageUrl = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? String
        self.ImageViewOne.downloadedFrom(link: ImageUrl!)

    })

} else {
    //
    }
    if ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Device2") != nil {

        ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Device2").observe(.value , with: {snapshot in
            let ImageUrl = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? String
            self.ImageViewTwo.downloadedFrom(link: ImageUrl!)
        })

    } else {
        //
    }
    if ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Device3") != nil  {

        ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Device3").observe(.value , with: {snapshot in
            let ImageUrl = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? String
            self.ImageViewThree.downloadedFrom(link: ImageUrl!)
        })

    } else {
        //
    }
```

But this actually gave me a signal SIGABRT error in

```
let ImageUrl = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? String
```

Not sure why this happens!

For downloadedFrom Function, [I'm using the extension from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/6297658)

Comment: comment out your  `.downloadedFrom( ` and see if you are you recieving your url from DB?

Comment: The error actually in line where I want to get the url! There's nothing wrong in the  `. downloadedFrom` function I have tried it in another project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing :-

```
 let ImageUrl = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? String
```

To -

```
 if let deviceDict = snapshot.value! as? [String : AnyObject]{
     let imageUrl = deviceDict["ImageUrl"] as! String
     self.ImageViewThree.downloadedFrom(link: ImageUrl!) 
     }
```

Comment: Then try printing `imageUrl` . If you get the desired result then i am sure there is some issue in `.downloadedFrom`

Comment: They seem right, but maybe , just maybe instead of extension try doing it in each code, the downloading part, though i haven't tested it , but maybe the `downloadFrom` function is being override even before it could give you back single image thus only giving one image , the last one. Maybe because its asynchronous.

Comment: It downloaded the images! but it takes to long to download them! Why?

Comment: If you are using the default pre loaded images in the stimulator photo library, they have size of about 3 MB. that could take time...